# Finding all possible combination of alphabets of length 5

Tags: python, performance

The code finds all the combination of alphabet with length 5 and saves it in a list(its ASCII value, minus 97). I want to optimize the code to reduce execution time.

```
from itertools import product
def permuteKey():

    def pp(chunks):
        return map(''.join, chunks)

    k=pp(product('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', repeat=5))
    key=[]
    for i in range(len(k)):
        temp=k[i]
        temp2=[]
        for j in range(len(temp)):
            temp1=temp[j]
            temp2.append(ord(temp1)-97)
        key.append(temp2)
        print key

permuteKey()
```

Comment: It is tough to understand what this code does.  You are likely to receive better reviews if you edit your question to explain in words what the code is supposed to do.  Could you give examples of expected output with smaller alphabets?

Comment: k=pp(product('ab', repeat=3))  Output is [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]

Comment: That is not words and is not output.

Comment: Dedent  `print key` so that it is not printed every run over the for loop but only after everything has been added to it

Comment: I agree, this post could use some bit more cleaning up. In the meantime, I refactored the code a bit (instead of the post).

Comment: What's the difference between your code and `[[i, j] for i in range(26) for j in range(26)]`? This has nothing to do with the combinations of the alphabet with a length of 5 does it?

Comment: I am using this block for my crypt-analysis assignment. The length may vary form 2 to n.  I don't see how this line is suitable for large n values. @JoeWallis

Comment: Your title says "of length 5", but your code produces results of length 2. Please clarify?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let me take a stab at this.

```
from itertools import product
def permuteKey():

    def pp(chunks):
        return map(''.join, chunks)

    k=pp(product('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', repeat=2))
    key=[]
    for i in range(len(k)):
        temp=k[i]
        temp2=[]
        for j in range(len(temp)):
            temp1=temp[j]
            temp2.append(ord(temp1)-97)
        key.append(temp2)
        print key

permuteKey()
```

Let's start by taking a look at the inner loop:

```
    temp=k[i]
    temp2=[]
    for j in range(len(temp)):
        temp1=temp[j]
        temp2.append(ord(temp1)-97)
```

First of all, you're only referring to `temp[j]` once, and never use `j` any further. The quick solution would be to iterato over `temp` instead:

```
    temp=k[i]
    temp2=[]
    for temp1 in temp:
        temp2.append(ord(temp1)-97)
```

But now we easily see that `temp2` can be written as a list comprehension:

```
    temp=k[i]
    temp2=[ord(temp1) - 97 for temp1 in temp]
```

The `temp = k[i]` can also be removed, leaving

```
    temp2=[ord(temp1) - 97 for temp1 in k[i]]
```

Now we end up with

```
from itertools import product
def permuteKey():

    def pp(chunks):
        return map(''.join, chunks)

    k=pp(product('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', repeat=2))
    key=[]
    for i in range(len(k)):
        temp2=[ord(temp1) - 97 for temp1 in k[i]]
        key.append(temp2)
        print key

permuteKey()
```

Again, we can apply the trick that `k[i]` is only used once:

```
from itertools import product
def permuteKey():

    def pp(chunks):
        return map(''.join, chunks)

    k=pp(product('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', repeat=2))
    key=[]
    for val in k:
        temp2=[ord(temp1) - 97 for temp1 in val]
        key.append(temp2)
        print key

permuteKey()
```

Another thing I notice, is that you never use the value of one of the items itself, but always `ord(c) - 97`. Why not just replace `abcd...xyz` with `range(26)`, and remove the `ord(...) - 97` part?

```
from itertools import product
def permuteKey():

    def pp(chunks):
        return map(''.join, chunks)

    k=product(range(26), repeat=2)
    key=[]
    for val in k:
        temp2=[temp1 for temp1 in val]
        key.append(temp2)
        print key

permuteKey()
```

But now we don't need `pp` anymore.

```
from itertools import product
def permuteKey():

    k=product(range(26), repeat=2)
    key=[]
    for val in k:
        temp2=[temp1 for temp1 in val]
        key.append(temp2)
        print key

permuteKey()
```

Also, the definition of `temp2` is now equal to `val`.

```
from itertools import product
def permuteKey():

    k=product(range(26), repeat=2)
    key=[]
    for val in k:
        temp1 = list(val)  # `val` is a tuple, but your code expects a list.
        key.append(temp1)
        print key

permuteKey()
```

Does it really matter that you want lists instead of tuples? I think not.

```
from itertools import product
def permuteKey():

    k=product(range(26), repeat=2)
    key=[]
    for val in k:
        key.append(val)
        print key

permuteKey()
```

Now, I have to wonder: why are we actually printing key at every step? I think you might have made a typo, so I'm going to assume you meant the following: (If not, skip the review from here).

```
from itertools import product
def permuteKey():

    k=product(range(26), repeat=2)
    key=[]
    for val in k:
        key.append(val)
    print key

permuteKey()
```

Now, it's bad practise to print inside a function. Better would it be to return the value.

```
from itertools import product
def permuteKey():

    k=product(range(26), repeat=2)
    key=[]
    for val in k:
        key.append(val)
    return key

print permuteKey()
```

Now, notice the similarity between `k` and `key`. `key = list(k)`.

```
from itertools import product
def permuteKey():

    k=product(range(26), repeat=2)
    return list(k)

print permuteKey()
```

But, now you have an intermediate value, you do not need it, and you can remove it.

```
from itertools import product
def permuteKey():
    return list(product(range(26, repeat=2)))

print permuteKey()
```

Now, I don't know how often you need `permuteKey`. If only once, you can write

```
from itertools import product
print list(product(range(26), repeat=2))
```

Comment: range() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: Ah, a minor typo. Put a `)` after the `26`, and remove the last one. I fixed the last code-block, so it should work now.

Comment: or have a function that takes the `length` as an argument and returns `list(product(range(26),repeat=length))` since you seem to want to repeat for a variable number of times

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: of course, if you need this multiple times, with or without variable lengths: yes.

Comment: Thank you @SjoerdJobPostmus. My coding is very messy. Have to work hard on it. Thanks for the solution. helps a lot